# Making a sliding view in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to know how I could create a row of buttons that you could slide right and left. For example in "Cut The Rope" you can slide left and right to find the box you want. How would I achieve this and also be able to add more buttons to it later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryScrollView: UIScrollView!
    var categoryArr = ["Button1","Button2","Button3","Button4","Button5"]
    var buttonColors = [UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.blackColor(), UIColor.cyanColor(), UIColor.magentaColor()]
    let kPadding:CGFloat = 10

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let buttonSize = CGSizeMake(categoryScrollView.bounds.size.width/2, categoryScrollView.bounds.size.height/2)//hal

        let scrollingView = colorButtonsView(buttonSize, buttonCount: 5)
        categoryScrollView.contentSize = scrollingView.frame.size
        categoryScrollView.addSubview(scrollingView)
        categoryScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        categoryScrollView.delegate = self
        categoryScrollView.pagingEnabled = true
        categoryScrollView.indicatorStyle = .Default
        categoryScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    }


    func colorButtonsView(buttonSize:CGSize, buttonCount:Int) -> UIView {
        let buttonView = UIView()
        buttonView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0,0)
        let padding = CGSizeMake(kPadding, kPadding)
        buttonView.frame.size.width = (buttonSize.width + padding.width) * CGFloat(buttonCount)
        var buttonPosition = CGPointMake(0, padding.height)
        let buttonIncrement = buttonSize.width + padding.width
        for i in 0...(buttonCount - 1)  {
            let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
            button.frame.size = buttonSize
            button.frame.origin = buttonPosition
            buttonPosition.x = buttonPosition.x + buttonIncrement
            button.setTitle(categoryArr[i], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            button.backgroundColor = buttonColors[i]
            buttonView.addSubview(button)
        }
        buttonView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        return buttonView
    }
}
extension ViewController:UIScrollViewDelegate{
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let index = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
        print(index)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question.

Comment: This code allowed for me to make buttons that scrolled sideways in which is what I wanted.

Comment: Nick wanted to have a scroll view where each page of the scroll contained a button. So basically you create a scroll view and then use the frame width (not content width) as one page of the scroll. Then you create a view which is equal to the size of each button multiplied by number of buttons + padding for each button and place it inside the scroll view. You add each button as sub view of that parent view. When the paging is enabled for the scroll view the scroll view will scroll per page bringing each button into the scroll view frame as you swipe.

Answer (score 0):

The scroll effect you want to achieve can be done with a `UIScrollView` or with a `UICollectionView`.

If you want to implement some kind of grid with multiple custom view it is better to use a `UICollectionView` because configuring the layout of a `UIScrollView` can be very tricky.

You can find some explication on how to set up a `UICollectionView` here : [Setting Up a UICollectionView in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654281/setting-up-a-uicollectionview-in-ios).
Its API is similar to a `UITableView` but it can scroll both horizontally and vertically. Just add your buttons inside `UICollectionViewCells` as you would do with `UITableViewCell`.